# Cannot access non-static field

Tags: c#

I can't figure out why it's looking for something static:

```
public class DatabaseBase
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public DatabaseBase(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }
}

public class MyDB : DatabaseBase
{
    readonly string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConnectionString"];

    public MyDB() : base(connectionString)
    {          
    }
}
```

I get Cannot access non-static field 'connectionString' in static context.  I don't see anything static in the base Database class so why??

here's another example of when we did kinda the same thing:

```
partial class Database : DatabaseBase
{
    static string DbConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            if (dbConnectionString == null)
                dbConnectionString = 
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConnectionString"];
            return dbConnectionString;
        }
    }
    public Database() :base(DbConnectionString)
    {
    }
```

ok so why did it have to be a static string for the connection string to be passed?

Answer (score 27):

We have worked hard to give error messages that are accurate, so read them carefully. The error message is telling you exactly what is going wrong: *you are accessing a non-static field in a context where it is only legal to access statics.*

So why is a base constructor call argument list a context where it is only legal to access statics?

When you call a base constructor, the arguments you pass *must not reference "this"*. Why? Because neither the derived constructor nor the base constructor for your "this" has run yet, and therefore "this" is almost certainly in an inconsistent, partially-initialized state. That is a recipe for crazy bugs. We therefore restrict you from accessing "this" until we know that at the very least, the base constructor has run.

This feature encourages sensible, well-ordered, understandable, maintainable and bug-free construction logic; I recommend working with, not against, those safeguards.

Comment: In this particular case, the *initializer* for the field `connectionString` **has** run already (initializers first, derived-to-base, then ctors, base-to-derived), so the parameter for the base ctor is initialized.

Comment: Of course, were this particular case valid, the different behaviours for the different cases would be confusing, so I understand why this wasn't special-cased. But I'm not sure if this holds for [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17342367/11545), a comment of which has led me here. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is in the MyDB constructor. <strike>The instance field (MyDB.connectionString) will not be initialized until the call to the base constructor returns, so everything inside `base( ... )` is in the static context.</strike> Just work with it...

```
public class MyDB : DatabaseBase
{
    static readonly string connectionString = 
          ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConnectionString"];
    public MyDB() : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

or better yet (as suggested by Simon Fox) ...

```
public class MyDB : DatabaseBase
{
    public MyDB() : base(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConnectionString"])
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: so then how can I send that connection string to the base constructor as required?

Comment: Your solutions are fine but your analysis is *completely incorrect*. The intstance field WILL be initialized before the base constructor is called. The order of construction goes: derived field initializers, base field initializers, base constructor body, derived constructor body.

Comment: See my articles on this subject for why the ordering is that way: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two.aspx