# Field initializer accessing `this`: invalid in C#, valid in Java?

Tags: c#, java, compiler-construction, initialization

### First, an introduction:

This code:

```
class C
{
    int i = 5;
    byte[] s = new byte[i];
}
```

fails to compile with the following error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `C.i'

Resharper says something similar: *Cannot access non-static field `i` in static context.*

This is inline with what the [C# spec says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) -- that a field initializer can't access the instance currently being created (`this`) or, by extension, any of the instance fields:

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the
>   instance being created. Thus, it is a compile-time error to reference
>   this in a variable initializer, as it is a compile-time error for a
>   variable initializer to reference any instance member through a
>   simple-name.

However, this works just fine in Java:

```
class C {
    int i = 5;
    byte s[] = new byte[i]; //no errors here
}
```

### Still with me? Ok, here's the question. Err, questions.

In a hypothetical world where this would be valid in C#, I'm wondering:  would it even **be possible**? If so, **what would be the pros and cons** that it would add to the table? 
Also, since it's really supported by Java, *do the same pros/cons hold* **for Java**? Or is there a **fundamental difference** in the way type initializers work in the two languages?

Comment: probably outside of any methods' context, properties are treated as static, if you don't provide it's exact source? My suggestion: Move your initializer to your constructor.

Comment: @GuyDavid What do you mean "props are treated as static" ?

Comment: The assumption came up at the moment I saw the compiler error- it searches for the static property `C.i`, and not `i`.

Comment: @GuyDavid The error message is clear in indicating that the field `i` is "the opposite of" *static*: cannot reference the **nonstatic** field [...] C.i

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I should have read it more carefully (So you should ignore my second comment). Still, if you add `static` to `i`, the error should disappear since out of the method's context it can only refer to non-member (class related, not instances) properties.

Comment: Can someone explain why the specifications limit the illegality to the case that you reference the instance member through a "*simple-name*"? What does that mean exactly? And what seemingly implied alternative mechanism would be legal?

Answer (score 13):

In short, the ability to access the receiver before the constructor body runs is a feature of marginal benefits that makes it easier to write buggy programs. The C# language designers therefore disabled it entirely. If you need to use the receiver then put that logic in the constructor body.

as for why the feature is legal in Java, you'll have to ask a Java designer.

Comment: Interestingly, TypeScript [just enabled](https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/94c3257db7e32f6723e43263525fbc1e42c04dac) this behavior.

Comment: @MgSam: Interesting; I no longer live with or work with any of the TypeScript designers so I'm not keeping up to date on the latest changes. I note that of course TypeScript has very different design principles than C#.

Answer (score 5):

In C#, field initializers are merely convenience semantics for the developer.  The compiler moves all field initializers into the body of the constructor *ABOVE* where the call is made to the base constructor.  So fields are initialized going up the ancestor chain, and the class is initialized from the base down.

Static references are ok because they are initialized before anything else.

Comment: Perfectly true. But this means it'd be illegal to use a field of the *base* type (which is not yet initialized) when evaluating an initializer. However, the previously-declared fields of *this* class should be within scope and initialized. So I can't see the connection between initializer call order and the restriction I'm asking about.

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu, as to why the field is not in scope you can read an answer given by the august and venerated Mr Lippert here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430787/cannot-access-non-static-field

Answer (score 2):

By no means is this an *authoritative* answer, but let me make an educated guess.

There **is** a fundamental difference, and I think the answers to the other questions are related to this difference.
It lies in order-of-type-initialization, especially in the context of inheritance.

So, how does instance initialization work?

### In C#:

- all instance field initializers run first, "up" the inheritance chain, from most derived to base class.
- then the ctors run, "down" the chain, from base to derived.

The possibility of ctors calling each-other or (explicitely) calling ctors of base classes doesn't change the situation, so I'll leave it out.

What basically happens is, this runs for each chass in the chain, starting with the most derived:

```
Derived.initialize(){
    derivedInstance.field1 = field1Initializer();
    [...]
    Base.Initialize();
    Derived.Ctor();
}
```

A simple example shows this:

```
void Main()
{
    new C();
}
class C: B {
    public int c = GetInt("C.c");
    public C(){
        WriteLine("C.ctor");
    }
}
class B {
    public int b = GetInt("B.b");
    public static int GetInt(string _var){
        WriteLine(_var);
        return 6;
    }
    public B(){
        WriteLine("B.ctor");
    }
    public static void WriteLine(string s){
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C.c
B.b
B.ctor
C.ctor
```

That means that *if* accessing fields in a field initializer was valid, I could do this disaster:

```
class C: B {
    int c = b; //b is a field inherited from the base class, and NOT YET INITIALIZED!
    [...]
}
```

### In Java:

Long, interesting article about type initialization [here](http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html). To summarize:

It's a bit more complicated, because besides the notion of instance field initializers, there's the notion of an (optional) *instance initializer*, but here's the gist of it:

Everything runs **down** the inheritance chain.

- the instance initializer of the **base** class runs
- the field initializers of the base class run
- the ctor(s) of the base class run
- repeat above steps for the next class down the inheritance chain.
- repeat previous step until reaching the most derived class.

Here's the proof: ([or run it yourself online](http://ideone.com/n42Zz4))

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
      new C();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    {
        WriteLine("init C");
    }
    int c = GetInt("C.c");

    public C(){
            WriteLine("C.ctor");
    }

}

class B {
    {
        WriteLine("init B");
    }
    int b = GetInt("B.b");

    public static int GetInt(String _var){
            WriteLine(_var);
            return 6;
    }
    public B(){
            WriteLine("B.ctor");
    }
    public static void WriteLine(String s){
            System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
init B
B.b
B.ctor
init C
C.c
C.ctor
```

What this means is, by the time a field initializer runs, all *inherited* fields are already initialized (by initializer OR ctor in base class), so it's safe enough to allow this behaviour:

```
class C: B {
    int c = b; //b is inherited from the base class, and it's already initialized!
    [...]
}
```

In Java, like in C#, the field initializers are run in the order of declaration.
The Java compiler even goes through the effort of checking that the field initializers aren't called out-of-order* :

```
class C {
    int a = b; //compiler error: illegal forward reference
    int b = 5;
}
```

---

* As an aside, you *can* access fields out-of-order if the initializer calls an instance method to do so:

```
class C {
    public int a = useB(); //after initializer completes, a == 0
    int b = 5;
    int useB(){
        return b;  //use b regardless if it was initialized or not.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because field initialisers are moved into the constructor by the compiler (unless static) and so you would need be explicit in your constructor like this:

```
class C 
{
    int i = 5;
    byte[] s;

    public C()
    {
        s = new byte[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer provides the workaround, which is obvious. It doesn't answer the *why*.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of a non-answer, but I like to think of anything in the body of a class as being sequence-independent.  It's not supposed to be sequential code that needs to be evaluated in a particular manner--it's just default state for the class.  If you use code like that, you're expecting i to be evaluated before s.

Anyways, you can just make i a const (as it should be), anyways.

Comment: Actually, initializers are *guaranteed* to be evaluated in the order they are declared: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645757%28v=VS.71%29.aspx (look for the phrase "textual order"). That said, I agree it's cleaner *not* to write code using this (somewhat obscure) assumption.