# Field initializer accessing 'this' reloaded

Tags: c#

This question is an extension of [Cristi Diaconescu's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342367/field-initializer-accessing-this-invalid-in-c-valid-in-java) about the illegality of field initializers accessing `this` in C#.

This is illegal in C#:

```
class C
{
    int i = 5;
    double[] dd = new double[i]; //Compiler error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property.
}
```

Ok, so the reasonable explanation to why this is illegal is given by, among others, [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342367/field-initializer-accessing-this-invalid-in-c-valid-in-java/17344750#17344750):

> In short, the ability to access the receiver before the constructor body runs is a feature of marginal benefits that makes it easier to write buggy programs. The C# language designers therefore disabled it entirely. If you need to use the receiver then put that logic in the constructor body.

Also, the C# specifications are pretty straightforward (up to a point):

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created. Thus, it is a compile-time error to reference this in a variable initializer, as it is a compile-time error for a variable initializer to reference any instance member ***through a simple-name***.

So my question is: what does "*through a simple-name*" mean?

Is there some alternative mechanism where this would be legal? I am certain that almost every word in the specification is there for a very specific reason, so what is the reason of limiting the illegality of this particular code to *references through simple names*?

**EDIT**: I've not worded my question too well. I'm not asking for the definition of "*simple-name*", I am asking about the reason behind limiting the illegality to that particular scenario. If it is always illegal to reference any instance member in any which way, then why specify it so narrowly? And if its not, then what mechanism would be legal?

Comment: Well, according to [Grammar, C.2.4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), a *simple-name* = identifier.

Comment: FWIW, if you declare i as `const int i = 5;`, you can use it as an array initializer...

Comment: @JerKimball Which is irrelevant to the question at hand, and also clearly something the OP already knows.

Comment: @Servy Ah - mea culpa, misread the question. (shame)

Comment: You're over-parsing the specification here. The clause you're referring to is intended to clarify that both `this.x`, where `this` is explicit, and the *simple-name* `x`, which is an alias for `this.x` are both illegal.  The specification cannot simply say that "using `this` is illegal" because that would then not be clear that the *implicit* use via a *simple-name* is also illegal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't possible, in the general case, to determine whether an expression refers to the object being constructed, so prohibiting it and requiring compilers to diagnose it would require the impossible. Consider

```
partial class A {
  public static A Instance = CreateInstance();
  public int a = 3;
  public int b = Instance.a;
}
```

It's possible, and as far as I know perfectly valid, even if it a horrible idea, to create an object with `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(A))`, set `A.Instance` to that, and then call the constructor. When `b` is initialised, the object reads its own `a` member.

```
partial class A {
  public static A CreateInstance() {
    Instance = (A)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(A));
    var constructor = typeof(A).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
    var helperMethod = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, typeof(void), new[] { typeof(A) }, typeof(A).Module, true);
    var ilGenerator = helperMethod.GetILGenerator();
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, constructor);
    ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    var constructorInvoker = (Action<A>)helperMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<A>));
    constructorInvoker(Instance);
    return Instance;
  }
}

static class Program {
  static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("A.Instance = (a={0}, b={1})", A.Instance.a, A.Instance.b);
  }
}
```

You can only get compiler errors for what's detectable at compile time.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was asking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691350%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> A simple-name consists of a single identifier.

I suppose they clarify this because `this.i` is equivalent to `i` within a class method, when no variable named `i` is in scope. They've already forbade the use of `this` outside of an instance method:

```
class C
{
    int i = 5;
    double[] dd = new double[this.i]; 
    //Compiler error: Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context.
}
```

If this language wasn't there, some might read this as meaning you could reference instance variables simply by omitting the keyword `this`.

The best alternative is to use a constructor:

```
class C
{
    int i = 5;
    double[] dd;
    C()
    {
        dd = new double[i];
    }
}
```

You can also do this:

```
class C
{
    public int i = 5;
}
class D
{
    double[] dd = new double[new C().i];
}
```

Thanks to the fact that the two members are in different classes, the order in which they are initialized is unambiguous.

Comment: But then simply stating that its illegal to reference any instance member would suffice wouldn't it? Why specify it so narrowly when the broader case is illegal to begin with? You are probably right but it seems like an unnecesarily convoluted way of specifying all possible scenarios if thats the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do really messed up stuff when unmanaged code comes into play.  Consider this:

```
public class A
{
    public int n = 42;
    public int k = B.Foo();

    public A()
    {

    }
}

public class B
{
    public static unsafe int Foo()
    {
        //get a pointer to the newly created instance of A 
        //through some trickery.  
        //Possibly put some distinctive field value in `A` to make it easier to find

        int i = 0;
        int* p = &i;
        //get p to point to n in the new instance of `A`

        return *p;
    }
}
```

I spent a bit of time trying to actually implement this (for kicks) but gave up after a bit.  That said, you can get a pointer to the heap and then just start looking around for something that you can recognize as an instance of `A` and then grab the `n` value from it.  It would be hard, but it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are just misreading the last sentence. The spec flatly states an instance field initializer cannot reference the instance being created. It is then simply citing examples. You cannot use `this` and for the same reason you cannot use a "simple-name" because a simple name access implicitly uses `this`. The spec is not narrowing the cases. It simply calling out some specific constructions that are illegal. Another one would be using `base` to access a protected field from a base class.

Comment: [That is not true.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17370159/1159478)  It is indeed possible for an instance field initializer to use another instance field; a working example is given.  You just can't do it through a simple name, as that's the only case that the compiler can detect at compile time that you are indeed doing this.  The qualification in the specs is indeed needed, not just one example.

Comment: @Servy I don't see how that applies. In that example, you won't access the instance that is being created. When `b` is initialized, `CreateInstance` has not yet returned and A.Instance is null.

Comment: That is not correct.  `A.Instance` is set in the first line of `CreateInstance`.  `A.Instance` will *not* be `null` when `b` is initialized.  Run the program to see for yourself.

Comment: @Servy I did. I get a null reference exception thrown in the static constructor.

Comment: Verify that you copied it properly.  I just re-ran it to be sure and it works fine for me.  What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @Servy OK. I see that behavior now. I'm not sure how relevant the example is to the specification of the C# language. Eric Lippert more or less points out that this is allowed in IL, but that it is extremely likely to lead to bugs, so the *language* disallows it. Perhaps the spec needs a clarification that the reference to the instance being created is by static analysis (rather than a runtime analysis). Similar to how it defines definite assignment.

Comment: It effectively does, by stating that it is only prohibited when accessed through the simple name.  That's the case the compiler can prohibit, and the specs reflect that.  The OP here was asking if that point of clarification really is needed.  The answer, yes, there are way of doing what the specs say is prohibited, but they all involve not accessing the instance field through the simple name.