# Why C# won't allow field initializer with non-static fields?

Tags: c#, language-design

Why  C# will allow this :

```
public class MyClass
{
  static int A=1;
  static int B=A+1;
}
```

But   won't allow (*"A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property"*) this

```
public class MyClass
{
   int A=1;
   int B=A+1;
}
```

I thought that it's the  *order* that is guaranteed (with static fields) to be sequential initialized as it appears  , but *it's also applied here* as you can see :

```
public class MyClass
{
   int A=((Func<int>)(delegate(){ Console.WriteLine ("A"); return 1;}))();
   int B=((Func<int>)(delegate(){ Console.WriteLine ("B"); return 2;}))();
   int C=((Func<int>)(delegate(){ Console.WriteLine ("C"); return 3;}))();
}

void Main()
{
 var a = new MyClass();
}
```

Result :

```
A
B
C
```

**Question**

I'm more interested with the *reason/logic* for why it was restricted. just for curiosity.

nb didn't find any duplicate.

Comment: My guess: because you don't need an instance to reference static fields. Granted, it seems you could *assume* the instance being initialized.

Comment: Paging @EricLippert :)

Comment: "Too broad?" Someone needs their voting privileges suspended. This is the exact opposite of broad.

Comment: Why won't it allow it? What compiler error do you get? Which SO results about that error did you read?

Comment: @CodeCaster added the error . _A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property_

Comment: oh lawd, dem casts:  `(() => Console.WriteLine("You don't need all those casts and delegates"))()`

Comment: I think your question is explained by Eric Lippert in linked [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342367/field-initializer-accessing-this-invalid-in-c-valid-in-java). If you think not, notify me and I'll remove the vote.

Comment: Personally I hate that statics can reference other statics like that without any kind of dependency analysis. I've seen bugs introduced because some one was "just cleaning up" or fixing "style issues".

Comment: I reopened the question as suggested duplicate is about something else. It doesn't explain why static fields can be accessed in static field initailizers but instance fields can't be accessed in instance field initializers. If community disagrees with me, can be closed again.

Comment: @Will NO. you still need the cast. the only thing you can save here is to replace anony method with lambda `((Func<int>)(() => { Console.WriteLine("A"); return 1; }))()` [FYI your code won't compile](http://i.imgur.com/qvS70z2.png)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Okay, ya got me there.  Still, delegates, eew.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I'm more interested with the reason/logic for why it was restricted. just for curiosity.

If you read the C# Language Spec, 10.11.3, it hints as to the rationale here.  In discussing *variable initializers*:

> It is useful to think of instance variable initializers and constructor initializers as statements that are automatically inserted before the constructor-body.

Since these are "inserted before the constructor", they are being executed prior to `this` being valid, so allowing you to refer to other members (effectively `this`) would be problematic.

Note that this is consistent with how `static` fields work, as well.  In both cases, you *are* allowed to access static data, but not instance data.  The error message you receive ("A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property") directly notes this.

Comment: Before the static constructor has ran(while in field initalizers), type will also be in invalid state. So why that is allowed to access static members? Doesn't makes sense for me.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel For static members, type is merely a scope. Nothing but syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Agent_L Not sure how your comment answers my question. My question is, if design decision that restricts the access of `this` reference in instance field initializers is because that object could be in invalid state, then same way before the static constructor has ran, Type will be in invalid state only. Why does the compiler allow you to access static members in static field initializers ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel There are only some cases when `this` can be used in partially-valid state, while all cases of type scope are valid all the time. I believe it would take quite an effort to make compiler smart enough to distinguish it, and even more difficult to explain in one short error message why some are invalid while others are ok. Now we're given very clear distinction: "Don't touch `this`" and I think this clarity has considerable value on its own.

Comment: For me this article explained it the best: http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2002_11/article4/  in C# constructors work differently than in Java

Answer (score 6):

"Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object." -[static <sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

When `A` and `B` are declared static they belong to the type `MyClass` and all instances of `MyClass` will have the same value for `A` and `B`. The static constructor will run before the class is instantiated but after the program has started. At that point, `A` is already defined, and thus `B` can reference it.

On the other hand, when `A` and `B` are not static, they only belong to the instance of `MyClass`. While compiling, the field `B` will attempt to be initialized based on a value from `A` which has not yet been initialized. There is no instance of `MyClass` while the compiler is running and therefore there is no value of `A` to reference.