# What is the use of field initialisers in .NET(apart from readability)?

Tags: .net, language-design

I am just trying to learn about field initializers. I ran into the error - field initializers cannot use non static field, method or prop. While hunting an answer for this I came across [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725571/why-c-sharp-wont-allow-field-initializer-with-non-static-fields/27725641#27725641) post.

Most up voted answer, to the post, suggests that 'this' doesn't exist until the constructor is called. Does anyone know why it is that way? Why couldn't 'this' have existed before field initializers are invoked?

In my mind, coming from a C/C++ background, 'this' is merely just a block of memory allocated on the heap. And it has to exist before any member of 'this' can be assigned a value. (So it definitely exists before field initializers).

Comment: Are you asking why the language designers decided to initialise fields before running the constructor?

Comment: You may want to include a bit of code showing the error when calling `this`, so that future readers can relate easily to this question. @TheLethalCoder The way I read it it's more about how `this` is initialized and why it isn't available at that point in time.

Comment: `this` does exist as you say, in the sense the memory is allocated. It's just not accessible to field initialisers. The reason is simple: until all the field initialisers have run, some fields are effectively in an invalid state. Rather than have some complex process of determining whether a field is valid at the point it's referenced, the language designers opted for the far simpler approach of forbidding access to `this`.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder yes, why the needless limitation if you are right about the language designer's act?

Comment: @DavidArno what is a potential invalid state? AFAIK there isn't one. B'cz even before the field initializers are run, the fields are initialized to their default value. And if an invalid state is "not being able to initialize", this can be caused even inside a constructor if you aren't careful about the order of initialization.

Answer (score 5):

When an object gets instantiated the follwing happens (simplified):

- memory is allocated
- field initializers are executed
- 'this' is created, linking all the (non-static) fields to this instance

When the field initializers are executed, the individual fields are not yet linked to the instance, so you cannot refer to another field (except the static ones) because that can only work through the reference in the 'this' instance (that does not exist yet).

To avoid confusion, you could choose not to use field initializers and initialise all the fields in the constructor body but the consequence is, you always need to explicitly declare a constructor.

Comment: Johan, are you suggesting it is by design. If so, what I don't get is why the unnecessary limitation?

Comment: Yes it is by design/choice: the initializers are executed before the body of the constructor.  This has a couple of advantages:
- there only needs to be one code block for the initializers, regardless of how many constructors you have
- the fields are initialized in the same way, regardless of which constructor is called (if you have multiple).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a field, use a property with a backing field and initialize it lazily.

For example, if you wanted to do this

```
class MyClass
{
    public string SomeField = this.SomeMethod();
}
```

use this

```
class MyClass
{
    private string _someField = null;

    public string SomeField
    {
        get
        {
            if (_someField == null) _someField = this.SomeMethod();
            return _someField;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `this` was available inside the initializers, it means you could access the values of *other* fields that have not had their initializers run yet (or even potentially the field you are *currently* initializing!). Consider:

```
class Foo
{
    private int a = this.b + 1;
    private int b = this.a + 2;

    public Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a = {0}, b = {1}", a, b);
    }
}
```

To avoid breaking memory safety and giving you access to uninitialized memory, these fields would have to be initialized *twice*, first with default values, then with the result of calling the initializer.

It's not unsolvable, but it's kind of weird. Hiding the current instance until all of its field initializers have finished running avoids this situation where you can see a partially-initialized object.

Comment: But wouldn't it be the case even if I were to move those two lines of initialization inside the constructor?

Comment: Yes, and that is a problem for C#. It means that fields that are initialized only in the constructor body do have to be implicitly initialized to their default values first before the constructor body runs. (Of course, the compiler can optimize a lot of the redundant initialization away.)

However, inside the constructor body, since you are in imperative code, it is at least clear which order the fields are initialized. That's not true at the declaration. In my (edited) example, what values would a and b have?