# Calling a class with Blazor failing "a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property"

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm just getting started in Blazor from Web Forms, & I'm very impressed. However, I'm struggling to figure out what my problem is here when calling a class in Blazor.

Trying to call the call like this:

```
@code {
testingClass t = new testingClass();
string Teststring = t.TestResponse();
}
```

The class in question:

```
 namespace BlazorTesting.Data
  {
    public class testingClass
    {
        public string TestResponse()
        {
            return "hello world";
        }    
    }
}
```

The problem line of code & what Visual Studio says the error is:

> ```
> string Teststring = t.TestResponse();
> a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property 'Component.t'
> ```

*It should be noted, I do have `@using BlazorTesting.Data` on my Razor page.*

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725571/why-c-sharp-wont-allow-field-initializer-with-non-static-fields?noredirect=1&lq=1 and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629756/what-is-the-use-of-field-initialisers-in-netapart-from-readability/45630105#45630105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not specific to Blazor... You cannot initialize `Teststring` with a value from something that is not yet exist.

> Instance fields cannot be used to initialize other instance fields
> outside a method. If you are trying to initialize a variable
> outside a method, consider performing the initialization inside the
> class constructor

Or a method such as the OnInitialized lifecycle method...

You can do that like this:

```
@code {
    testingClass t = new testingClass();
    string Teststring => t.TestResponse();

    public class testingClass
    {
        public string TestResponse()
        {
            return "hello world";
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do that like the code snippet below, which is the preferred way:

```
@code {
    // Define the variables
    testingClass t;
    string Teststring;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
         // Instantiate your object 
         t = new testingClass();
         // and then use it
        Teststring = t.TestResponse();
    }

    public class testingClass
    {
        public string TestResponse()
        {
            return "hello world";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard C# error, not specific to Blazor.
You will have to execute TestResponse() later, OnInitialized() is a good spot.

```
@code 
{
  testingClass t = new testingClass();
  string Teststring;

  protected override OnInitialzied()
  {
    Teststring = t.TestResponse();
  }
}
```

beware of the `null` cases, but for a string that shouldn't be much of a problem.