# How to iterate a public constant with a value obtained by a webclient?

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

I'm coding some stuff and my pointers are inside a GitHub repo so I use the client.DownloadString("rawgithubEtc.com"); to get them, but I want to make a PUBLIC variable with the pointer, so the request will be done just ONE TIME, I tried this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    public string stuff = client.DownloadString("rawgithubetc.com");
    public int speedTimer = 0; public string speed_data;
    Overlay frm = new Overlay();
    public Mem m = new Mem();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

..but Visual Studio says:

> a field initializer can't be used to reference the field, method or non static properties.

..in the .client here:

```
public string stuff = client.DownloadString("rawgithubetc.com");
```

Comment: You need to provide a variable _name_ when declaring a variable. There are other huge issues with the code you posted, such as public fields, improper coupling of UI and non-UI code, etc. But the immediate problem causing the problem you seem to be asking about is that you simply did not include a variable name where one is required.

Comment: You're missing some stuff from your example code, like variable names.  How can we figure out where you're trying to use the download without a variable name?

Comment: sorry, dont downvote me, I have modfied it

Comment: Also, whatever translation tool you used spit out "camp" when the correct word in English discussions of C# is "field".

Comment: sorry, modified now

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725571/why-c-sharp-wont-allow-field-initializer-with-non-static-fields

Answer (score 0):

You can't use one field inside the initialization expression of another field.  But you can move the initialization to the constructor body and things will work just fine.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    public string stuff; /* not allowed to use "client" here */
    public Form1()
    {
        /* using "client" here is perfectly fine */
        stuff = client.DownloadString("rawgithubetc.com");
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```