# singleton pattern should create multiple instances of DBContext but doesnt

Tags: singleton, entity-framework-5

I need to be able to connect to 2 databases at the same time.  The databases have the same structure, so I think that I should be able to use 2 instances of the same context.  However I cant get it to work. 
As soon as I set the connection string for the second instance the connection string for the first instance changes to match it.  Is there something about EF that I am missing?

I have the following helper class to create a context.

```
public class SettingsHelper
{
    private static SettingsHelper instance;
    public static SettingsHelper Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new SettingsHelper();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

   public static Context CreateContext(string constr )
    {
        try
        {

            var db = new Context(constr);
            return db;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException.Show(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The actual context class contains

```
 public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    { 
          // some code
     }
 }
```

If I create two contexts in the following way

```
        using (Context firstContext = SettingsHelper.CreateContext( "conn1" ))
        {
                // firstContext has connection string "conn1"
            using (Context secondContext = SettingsHelper.CreateContext("conn2"  ))
            {
               //  firstcontext now has the same connection string "conn2"
            }
        }
```

conn1 and conn2 are defined in app.config

Here is my context. 
I wonder if my problem was because _connectionString is static?  However  if I change it to public I get an error in the context initialiser " cannot access non static field in static context "

```
public class Context : DbContext
 {
    static string _connectionString;

    public Context()
        : base(_connectionString ?? "Syrius")  
    {
    }

   public Context(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {
        _connectionString = connString;
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Migrations.Configuration>());
    }

    public Context(string connString, int TimeOutSecs)
        : base(connString)
    {
       _connectionString = connString;
    }

    public DbSet<Label> Labels { get; set; }
    // etc
 }
```

Comment: What is the question? What do you want to know?

Comment: I edited and clarified the question

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. The problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: i added my context code , is the problem in that?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430787/cannot-access-non-static-field' seems relevant... just thinking it through

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by creating a global connection string

> ```
> public static class DataGlobals
> {
>     private static string _connectionString = "";
>     public static string ConnectionString
>     {
>         get { return _connectionString; }
>         set { _connectionString = value; }
>     }
> }
> ```

I set and call the global whenever I need it.

also I added a factory method

```
public class MyContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<Context>
{
    public Context Create()
    {
        return new Context(DataGlobals.ConnectionString );
    }
}
```